# DllImport native dependency from NuGet package not working on net472, but works netcoreapp2.2

Tags: .net, nuget, pinvoke

My project currently works flawlessly on .NET Core (Linux/OSX/Windows/`netcoreapp2.2`). It *should* work on `net472` as well, but for some reason, `DllImport` isn't finding the native dependency.

A simple repro can be found [here](https://github.com/qmlnet/qmlnet-examples/blob/net-framework-test/src/Features/Program.cs#L18), but I will expand further in this question for posterity.

Here is the project that is packed that contains the native dependency.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <Import Project="../../build/common.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>true</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\net\Qml.Net\Qml.Net.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="output/**/*">
      <PackagePath>runtimes/win-x64/native/</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This will produce a NuGet package with the following output.

```
├── [Content_Types].xml
├── package
│   └── services
│       └── metadata
│           └── core-properties
│               └── e803485f4a674e8d9d0155224fa9cbc2.psmdcp
├── Qml.Net.WindowsBinaries.nuspec
├── _rels
└── runtimes
    └── win-x64
        └── native
            └── QmlNet.dll

8 directories, 4 files
```

Here is my consuming project.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <RunWorkingDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</RunWorkingDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="**\*.qmlc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Qml.Net" Version="0.9.0-alpha.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Qml.Net.WindowsBinaries" Version="0.9.0-alpha.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="images\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    <Content Include="pages\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    <Content Include="Main.qml" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And here is the simple code that is trying to do the PInvoke.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Qml.Net.Runtimes;

namespace Features
{
    class Program
    {
        // NOTE: This works if I provide absolute path to QmlNet.dll
        [DllImport("QmlNet")]
        internal static extern long qml_net_getVersion();

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This is need to prep Qt runtime that QmlNet.dll depends on.
            // It is required, but it is irrelvant to the issue we are experiencing.
            RuntimeManager.DiscoverOrDownloadSuitableQtRuntime();

            // The following works on netcoreapp2.2, but not on 4.7.2.
            Console.WriteLine(qml_net_getVersion());

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'QmlNet': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
```

I tried adding an explicit target to `net472` in my NuGet package, didn't work.

I don't get any errors when my consuming project targets `netcoreapp2.2`.

How do I get my native dependency to be property discovered with `DllImport` when targeting `net472`?

Comment: If you run `dotnet publish` on the exe project, does `QmlNet.dll` get copied into the publish output directory? If so, does running the exe from the publish directory work?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60224214/3359365) helped me get my native file loaded from my nuget package. The only thing I did extra was use the current directory like this

```cs
private static IntPtr ImportResolver(string libraryName, Assembly assembly, DllImportSearchPath? searchPath)
{
    IntPtr libHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    //TODO: Add check for windows if needed.
    if (libraryName == WrapperFFI && RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) && Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    {
        var res = NativeLibrary.TryLoad(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libwrapper_ffi.so", out libHandle);
        if (!res) {
            res = NativeLibrary.TryLoad(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libwrapper_ffi.so", out libHandle);
        }
    } 
    return libHandle;
}
```

Edit:

Even though the above fix will work for most it did not work when I pulled my nuget package built on a private repo. The private repo's native lib gets built on centos which results in a smaller binary, but I still get unable to load exception on my ubuntu dev machine. The centos lib had more dependencies shown by ldd than the one built on ubuntu

Ubuntu:

[image]

Centos:

[image]

So I will just create an ubuntu build boks to quickly get around the issue